# Inconsistent implementation of collections.abc

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

I'm trying to understand [`collections.abc`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/_collections_abc.py) source code.

Let's take a look on `Hashable` class' `__subclasshook__` implementation:

```
@classmethod
def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
    if cls is Hashable:
        for B in C.__mro__:
            if "__hash__" in B.__dict__:
                if B.__dict__["__hash__"]:
                    return True
                break
    return NotImplemented
```

Here we first of all check that there is property `hash` and than check that it has non-false value. This logic is also presented in `Awaitable` class.

And `AsyncIterable` class' `__subclasshook__`:

```
@classmethod
def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
    if cls is AsyncIterable:
        if any("__aiter__" in B.__dict__ for B in C.__mro__):
            return True
    return NotImplemented
```

Here we just check that there is `__aiter___` property, and this logic is presented in any other classes from this package.

Is there any reason for this logic difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`__hash__` protocol](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) explicitly allows flagging a class as unhashable by setting `__hash__ = None`.

> If a class [...] wishes to suppress hash support, it should include `__hash__ = None` in the class definition.

The reason is that `a == b` always requires `hash(a) == hash(b)`. Otherwise, `dict`, `set` and similar data structures break. If a child class changes `__eq__` explicitly or otherwise, this may no longer hold true. Thus, `__hash__` can be flagged as not applicable.

Comment: This however doesn't explain why also `Awaitable` does this.

Comment: @Bakuriu I'd speculate it's from copy-pasting, seeing how `Awaitable` is defined right after `Hashable`. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Awaitable) mention that `Awaitable` doesn't always work properly, so the ABC may not be finalized. Strictly speaking, nothing forbids other ABCs to do the checking of `Hashable` anyways.